# Getting Error : " CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h: No such file or directory" while implementing Core-Plot in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios4, charts, core-plot

I am getting the following error when I try to implement Core-Plot in my iPhone app.

> CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h: No such file or directory

I downloaded installed the Core-plot package from the below link

http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/w/list

Still it does not seem to work and gives error as mentioned above.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you linking the static library or using the SDK? Did you use one of the release builds or are you building from latest source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this [link](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications), and add `-all_load` and `-Objc` in other linker Flags (get info -> build (in linking section you find other linker flags)).

And give complete path in header search paths (in search path section) for your core-plot framework. Looks like `.../core-plot/framework`.

Comment: Note that the Switch on the Code tutorial was written a while ago, and much of the API has changed since then.  A better place to start would be the installation instructions on the Core Plot wiki: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications

Comment: the link that you have provided is for different version... Can you provide me link for xcode 4.0....

Comment: Looks like the link has died again Ishu (I get "There was an error obtaining wiki data:"). Would you update it, or remove it if you can do so whilst preserving the crux of the answer?

Answer (score 1):

This helped as well

```
Header Search Paths -> "${PROJECT_DIR}/Your Project Name/CorePlot_0.9/Source/framework"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check at HEADER SEARCH PATHS if seted to recursive and not non-recursive